# Why showing this "Papertrail is a legacy winston transport. Consider upgrading"

Tags: winston, papertrail-app

I am using Winston version

```
"winston": "^3.2.1",
"winston-papertrail": "^1.0.5"
```

When I add

transports: [ new winston.transports.Papertrail({})]

I get

Papertrail is a legacy winston transport. Consider upgrading: 
- Upgrade docs: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md

why this message show and how do I stop to showing this.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://github.com/kenperkins/winston-papertrail/issues/88

Replacing the winston-papertrail install with:

`npm install https://github.com/kenperkins/winston-papertrail.git#v2 --save`

Seems to do the trick.